# wcf service for monodroid application

Tags: wcf, xamarin.android

I'm having difficulties with accessing a WCF service. My service is 
running in the same solution as the MonoDroid App and is hosted by visual 
studio. I configured it as BasicHttp. The reference adds ok but at runtime 
when I call the one simple test method, I get:

> System.Net.WebException: Error: ConnectFailure (Connection refused).

I'm calling the service on localhost:51559.
Could this be a similar issue to cross domain web service querying with JQuery?
Is the request seen as coming from localhost (the emulator) as well?

AsI found that on calling my wcf service to web application are working fine but on monodroid application same wcf service giving error System.Net.WebException: Error: ConnectFailure (Connection refused)

Thanks to anyone who takes interest in this.

Answer (score 0):

add below `system.diagnostics` tag in your WCF app.config and see transport level activity.If found any SVC log in SVC log file then it's service blocking your call other wise your client issue.i dont knw monodroid so i cant help you 4 same.

you can find svc loag in service dir after enable SVC log...

```
<system.diagnostics>
<sources>
  <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging" switchValue="Warning, ActivityTracing">
    <listeners>
      <add name="ServiceModelTraceListener" />
    </listeners>
  </source>
  <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Verbose,ActivityTracing">
    <listeners>
      <add name="ServiceModelTraceListener" />
    </listeners>
  </source>
  <source name="System.Runtime.Serialization" switchValue="Verbose,ActivityTracing">
    <listeners>
      <add name="ServiceModelTraceListener" />
    </listeners>
  </source>
</sources>
<sharedListeners>
  <add initializeData="App_tracelog.svclog" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" name="ServiceModelTraceListener" traceOutputOptions="Timestamp" />
</sharedListeners>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `LocalHost` in your url, use your systems ip address